# Using C on RPI to Initiate a File Transfer from Raspberry Pi to PC

Tags: ssh, c

As the title suggests, I would like to have the **RPI initiate a file transfer** to the PC. I am thinking to make a `system()` call inside the C code running on the RPI. I have established an SSH connection between the two but from my understanding, the remote server/ Rpi cannot call `scp` to send a file to the host PC. Can anyone give me some hints about what I should look into? Thanks

Comment: please be aware that you are asking about a file transfer between a linux computer and a PC ... the question is not Raspberry Pi specific

Comment: WHY don't you `ssh` into the PC?

Comment: because i don't have a monitor connected to the RPI

Comment: I don't have a monitor connected to my Pis.  That is WHY I ssh into them.

Comment: I use cron to copy files from my Pi to a Linux PC.

Answer (score 1):

If your **local host** (the Windows PC) runs an SSH server daemon, I don't know why your RPi couldn't initiate an `scp` connection a file. Here's an example I just used to verify this works:

```bash
pi@raspberrypi3b:~ $ scp /home/pi/testsearch.txt pi@raspberrypi4b:/home/pi
```

Here's what happened:

From host `raspberrypi3b`, I made an `scp` transfer **from** the `raspberrypi3b` **to** the `raspberrypi4b`.

Upon execution of this command the `scp` tool copied the file at `raspberrypi3b:/home/pi/testsearch.txt` to `raspberrypi4b:/home/pi/testsearch.txt`. This works as expected.

Then I made a similar transfer between `raspberrypi3b`, and my macbook:

```
pi@raspberrypi3b:~ $ scp /home/pi/testsearch.txt seamus@dung-pro.local:/Users/seamus/
```

This also worked.

That leads me to the conclusion that you either entered your command incorrectly, **or** your Windows(??) PC is not running an SSH server with the necessary access permissions. Whaddya' think?

I think another way to accomplish your objective that avoids setting up an SSH server on your PC is to set up a ***share*** on your Windows host, and then simply have your RPi `mount` that share before making the file transfer. Would that work in your scenario?